# Smarty : How to delete part of url?

Tags: smarty

I'm displaying current url with :
[https://mywebsite.com/{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URL}](https://mywebsite.com/%7B$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URL%7D)
So i obtain : https://mywebsite.com/shop1/mycategory/myproduct/ or https://mywebsite.com/shop2/mycategory/myproduct/ depending on the shop i'm connected on.

I need to delete the /shop1 or /shop2 in the url

How to do that ? Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://mywebsite.com/{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URL|replace:'shop1/':''|replace:'shop2/':''}
```